# how i can decode labels "Internal Server Error" using Flask

Tags: machine-learning, flask, deployment, encoder-decoder

i try to deploy my model using random forest classifier but there is error with my app.py code

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
import pickle
import numpy as np

app = Flask(__name__)

# Load the saved model, label encoder, and scaler
with open("ml_model.pkl", "rb") as model_file:
    model = pickle.load(model_file)
with open("label_encoder.pkl", "rb") as label_encoder_file:
    label_encoder = pickle.load(label_encoder_file)
with open("scaler.pkl", "rb") as scaler_file:
    scaler = pickle.load(scaler_file)

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template("index.html")

@app.route("/predict", methods=["POST"])
def predict():
    # Get user input from the HTML form
    country = request.form["country"]
    bachelor_majors = request.form["bachelor_majors"]
    ielts = float(request.form["ielts"])
    recommendations = int(request.form["recommendations"])
    sat = int(request.form["sat"])

    try:
        # Debugging: Print the values to check if they are correctly received
        print("Country:", country)
        print("Bachelor Majors:", bachelor_majors)
        print("IELTS:", ielts)
        print("Recommendations:", recommendations)
        print("SAT:", sat)
        # Transform user input using the label encoder and scaler
        country_encoded = label_encoder.transform([country])[0]
        bachelor_majors_encoded = label_encoder.transform([bachelor_majors])[0]
        user_data = np.array([[country_encoded, bachelor_majors_encoded, ielts, recommendations, sat]])
        scaled_data = scaler.transform(user_data)

        # Make a prediction using the model
        prediction = model.predict(scaled_data)

        # Transform the predicted value back to the university name
        predicted_university = label_encoder.inverse_transform(prediction)[0]


        return render_template("result.html", predicted_university=predicted_university)

    except KeyError as e:
        # Handle the case where the label is not recognized
        print("Error:", str(e))
        return render_template("result.html", predicted_university="Label not recognized")



if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

the error is when i try to enter categorical values such as United States that is in my dataset it give me this .. what is my mistake ?

```
raise ValueError(f"y contains previously unseen labels: {str(e)}")
ValueError: y contains previously unseen labels: 'United States'
```

here are the output
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T3xMV.png)

Comment: Welcome! First, it could be hard to guess why `label_encoder` fails to process a label without knowledge of what that pickled object is. Second, looking at the exception block, it seems reasonable to catch both `KeyError` and `ValueError` like: `except (KeyError, ValueError) as e:`.